# How to remove route at runtime?

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am using a third party nuget called AttributeRouting which registeres routes using attributes. I have a unique situation and i need to remove a route from the route table on Application_Start or similar. How can this be done?

I have supplied a screenshot of the route i want to remove. I have even named it "RemoveMePlease".
[image]

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class MvcApplication : admin.project.Global
{
    protected override void Application_Start()
    {
        base.Application_Start();

        int iRoute = 0;
        while (iRoute < RouteTable.Routes.Count)
        {
            bool isLastRoute = (iRoute == (RouteTable.Routes.Count - 1));

            RouteBase route = RouteTable.Routes[iRoute];

            if (!isLastRoute && route is AttributeRoute)
            {
                AttributeRoute currentRoute = route as AttributeRoute;
                int maxRouteIndex = RouteTable.Routes.Count - 1;
                for (int iDup = maxRouteIndex; iDup >= (iRoute + 1); iDup--)
                {
                    if (RouteTable.Routes[iDup] is AttributeRoute)
                    {
                        var potentialDupRoute = RouteTable.Routes[iDup] as AttributeRoute;

                        if (currentRoute.Url.Equals(potentialDupRoute.Url)) //-- routes match on url
                        {
                            //-- do httpMethods also match?
                            //-- AttributeRouting <=3.1
                            ICollection<string> currentHttpMethods = ((currentRoute.Constraints["httpMethod"]) as HttpMethodConstraint).AllowedMethods;
                            ICollection<string> potentialHttpMethods = ((potentialDupRoute.Constraints["httpMethod"]) as HttpMethodConstraint).AllowedMethods;

                            //-- AttributeRouting > 3.1
                            ICollection<string> currentHttpMethods = (currentRoute.Constraints["inboundHttpMethod"] as AttributeRouting.Web.Mvc.Constraints.InboundHttpMethodConstraint).AllowedMethods;
                            ICollection<string> potentialHttpMethods = (potentialDupRoute.Constraints["inboundHttpMethod"] as AttributeRouting.Web.Mvc.Constraints.InboundHttpMethodConstraint).AllowedMethods;


                            IEnumerable<string> matchedHttpMethods = currentHttpMethods.Intersect(potentialHttpMethods);

                            //-- remove the route
                            if (matchedHttpMethods.Count() == currentHttpMethods.Count()) RouteTable.Routes.Remove(currentRoute);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            iRoute++;
        }
    }
}
```